# C++ /Cli Passing data to child form (and back) or how to pass an object to a child form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am starting out with C++\Cli so be gentle ;-)

It seems my issue is not uncommon, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me, i.e. that I am able to implement.

I create an object "Genome" in say Form1_Load(), which I then want to provide with data in a child Form3 that is displayed via a tool strip menu. The object is provided with default system data in the constructor. This default data needs to be send to the child form as starting values in the input fields. After the user has accepted or modified this data, the object needs to be modified accordingly, after which the child form is closed.

My feeling is that this could be done by sending a pointer / handle to the object to the child form, making the data accessible.

Two issues: 1) basic, and 2) less basic.

1) The ToolstripMenuItem_Click action does not see the object created in Form1_Load.

2) I cannot seem to figure out how to pass (a handle) to the object with the ToolStripMenuItem_click event such that the object data is accessible in the child form.

Here's some code, I've stripped out as much as I can, I hope not too much (data hiding still to do):

Genome.h

```
ref class Genome
{
public:
    int nTFA; // nr of Transcription Factor genes
    int nFDE; // nr of Function cell Death genes

    List<char>^ cString;    // chromosome string 
    List<Gene^>^ cStruct;   // structure consisting of a List with Gene objects

    // methods
    void loadIniGen(String^ iniFile);   // load genome values from .ini file

    Genome(void);
};
```

Genome.cpp (methods and lots of vars left out):

```
// constructor
Genome::Genome(void)
{
    nTFA    = 20; // nr of Transcription Factor genes

    cString = gcnew List<char>();
    cStruct = gcnew List<Gene^>();
}
// methods
```

Form1.h

```
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {
         Genome^ myGenome = gcnew Genome(); // instantiate genome object
         }

private: System::Void genomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {
             Form3^ genomeForm = gcnew Form3(myGenome); // pass genome object to Form3 for data input
             genomeForm->Text = "Genome settings";

             genomeForm->StartPosition = FormStartPosition::CenterParent;
             genomeForm->ShowDialog(); // modal

         }
```

Thanks, Jan

Let's add the errors:

1) Gives this: error C2065: 'myGenome' : undeclared identifier

2) Gives this: error C3673: 'GenomeV2::Form3' : class does not have a copy-constructor (when I create the myGenome object in the ToolStrip action for testing)

To clarify, Form3 is designed, but has no functionality yet. Summary:

```
namespace GenomeV2 {

public ref class Form3 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form3(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form3()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox1;

etc.

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

etc.

#pragma endregion

private: System::Void Form3_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {
         numericUpDown1->Minimum = 10;  // TFA nr of Transcription Factor genes
         numericUpDown1->Maximum = 100;
etc.
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got it to work. Wheter it is the proper way, or if it can be improved, let me know!

1) Making `myGenome` visible

I've put the variable declaration of `Genome^ myGenome;` in the `Form1` public declaration so it is visible to all actions, and then I create the object in the `Form1_Load` event with `myGenome = gcnew Genome();` This can later be changed to a List with Genome objects etc.

2) Passing data between forms back and forth

As advised by David I pass the (now visible) `myGenome` object to `Form3` when instantiating genomeForm with `Form3^ genomeForm = gcnew Form3(myGenome);`. In the `Form3` declaration I create a `bGenome` object as a copy to take the data passed to the form. This is done in the constructor of `Form3` (see code below). This `bGenome` object contains a copy of the data of the `myGenome` object of Form1, that I can use to populate the numericUpDown fields of `Form3`, i.e. data transfer from `Form1` to `Form3`.

When all data is reviewed and modified where required, the form is closed with OK. At that moment, the data entered in the numericUpDown fields is copied back to the `bGenome` object.

Since `Form3` is `#included` in `Form1` (`Form1` is not `#included` in `Form3` to avoid a circular reference), `Form1` has access to `bGenome` and the data of `bGenome` can be copied back to `myGenome`, closing the loop: data transfer from `Form3` back to `Form1`.

*Note: I realise that `Form1` could also read out the numericUpDown fields of `Form3` as it has access, but I think it is cleaner to leave those in `Form3` and only feed back one complete modified object `bGenome` that can then be copied to `myGenome` in one statement.*

The object `myGenome` was used to populate the input fields to the user and the (revised) input is fed back to `myGenome`.

Code, all non-essentials stripped out.

Form1.h

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:
    Genome^ myGenome;

etc.

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
     {
         myGenome = gcnew Genome(); // instantiate genome object
     }

etc.

private: System::Void genomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
     {
         Form3^ genomeForm = gcnew Form3(myGenome); // pass genome object to Form3 for data input
         genomeForm->ShowDialog(); // modal

         myGenome->nTFA = genomeForm->bGenome->nTFA; // feed data from Form3 back to myGenome
         textBox1->Text = myGenome->nTFA.ToString();
     }
```

Form3.h

```
public ref class Form3 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Genome^ bGenome;

public:
    Form3(Genome^ aGenome)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bGenome = gcnew Genome();
        bGenome = aGenome;
    }

etc.

private: System::Void Form3_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
         numericUpDown1->Minimum = 10;  // TFA nr of Transcription Factor genes

etc.

         numericUpDown1->Value = bGenome->nTFA; // show the current Genome data in the input field
     }

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
     {
         bGenome->nTFA = Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDown1->Value); // copy the (modified) input data back into the Genome object

etc.
         this->DialogResult = System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK;
         this->Close();
     }
```

I would like to be able to do away with the local copies (`aGenome` and `bGenome`) and access `myGenome` directly from `Form3`, so if there is a way to do that, let me know. I have a feeling this could be done by passing `Form1` to `Form3` and `#include` `Form1` in the .cpp version of `Form3` (to avoid the circular ref.), but haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Error C2065: You need to store the `myGenome` object somewhere that other methods can see it. Right now, it's a local variable within the `Form1_Load` method. Make it a class field, and other methods within that object can see it.

   ```
   ref class Genome
   {
   public:
       Genome^ myGenome;
   };
   ```
2. Error C3673: If you haven't already, add a constructor to `Form3` that takes a `Genome^`. Once that is done, and you've made the above change to the storage of `myGenome`, then this line should compile.
3. "After the user has accepted or modified this data, the object needs to be modified accordingly, after which the child form is closed." You're passing the object itself, the child form will modify it directly. You shouldn't need to do any manipulation of `myGenome` in `genomeToolStripMenuItem_Click` after `ShowDialog` returns.

Comment: Oeps... missed the rest. 1) The intention is to create many Genomes, myGenome is just one to test, so creating myGenome in the class definition may not be practical, 2) I assume I need to add an additional constructor in the class definition? (genomeForm does not exist). What would that look like, Genome(Genome^) in the .h file? and how in the .cpp file? 3) Agree!

Comment: 1) So, a list of `Genome` objects? (i.e., `List<Genome^>^`)? If that's not appropriate, a single Genome named `activeGenome`, and you set the value in places other than just `Form_Load`? 2) Sorry, careless mistake: Add a constructor to `Form3`, or just modify the existing one to add a `Genome^` parameter.

Comment: 1) Yes indeed a list of Genome objects is what it will be, but typically I would create that object outside the class definition as it is a different object filled with objects from the Genome class. And yes I need to find a way to make the objects created known to the rest of the program. So far I have been able to create the main program thread in the FormLoad() section calling all objects and methods from there. 2) Not sure how to do that. If I just add Genome::Genome(Genome^){} to Form3 I get all kinds of errors. Genome(Genome^) doesn't work either. I added the code of Form3 for reference.

Comment: I did not read your comment properly. If I do this: Form3(Genome^ aGenome), I get following errors: warning C4677: 'Form3': signature of non-private member contains assembly private type 'Genome', and error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Genome'